# C Function returns correct results in first run but false in second+ runs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am creating a program that computes what was the last time a number was shown in a number of lotteries. The thing is that I have created two function , one that returns an array and one that short the array and prints the results , BUT when I first run the function from my program it prints the correct results but in the second ,third etc it produces wrong results .

Also I would like to say that the array stored in *database doesnt change!

//First function

```
void LateJoker(int *database){
            int i,j,k;
            int *numbersCount,numbersSeen[21];
            int numbersShort[21],max,pos,tmp;
            int size = *database;
            int *memAddress;
            int currentNumber;
            int countBreak;
            /*

            for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
                numbersCount[i]=0;

            for (i=size*SIZEOFRAW;i>=10;i-=10){
                memAddress = database + i;

                numbersSeen[*(memAddress +9)] = 1;


                for(k=1;k<=20;k++){
                    if (numbersSeen[k] != 1){
                        numbersCount[k] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }*/
            numbersCount = LateJokerRet(database);
            //short the numebrsCount array (insertion short)
            for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
                numbersShort[i] = i;

            for (i=1;i<=19;i++){
                pos = i;
                for (j=i+1;j<=20;j++){
                    if (numbersCount[pos] < numbersCount[j]){
                        pos = j;
                    }
                }
                if (pos != i){
                    tmp = numbersCount[pos];
                    numbersCount[pos] = numbersCount[i];
                    numbersCount[i] = tmp;

                    tmp = numbersShort[i];
                    numbersShort[i] = numbersShort[pos];
                    numbersShort[pos] = tmp;
                }
            }

            for (i=1;i<=20;i++){
                printf("%d=%d  ",numbersShort[i],numbersCount[i] );
                if (i % 5 == 0) printf("\n");
            }
            free(numbersCount);
        }
```

//Second fuction that calculates the array

```
int *LateJokerRet(int *database){
            int i,j,k;
            int *numbersCount,numbersSeen[21];
            int size = *database;
            int *memAddress;
            int currentNumber;


            numbersCount = (int *) calloc (21,sizeof(*numbersCount));

            for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
                numbersCount[i]=0;

            for (i=size*SIZEOFRAW;i>=10;i-=10){
                memAddress = database + i;

                numbersSeen[*(memAddress +9)] = 1;


                for(k=1;k<=20;k++){
                    if (numbersSeen[k] != 1){
                        numbersCount[k] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }


            return  numbersCount;
        }
```

Correct output:

```
14=111  16=74  12=47  7=42  5=39  
18=27  3=18  4=17  17=16  15=13  
10=12  13=10  9=9  11=7  20=6  
1=5  8=4  6=2  2=1  19=0
```

Wrong output:

```
14=111  16=74  12=47  7=42  18=27  
3=18  17=16  15=13  10=12  13=10  
9=9  11=7  20=6  1=5  8=4  
6=2  2=1  5=0  19=0  4=0
```

As you can see the wrong numbers are only 5 and 4 .

What is wrong ? :/

Comment: What value is `SIZEOFRAW`?

Comment: You know arrays in C are zero-based, don't you?

Comment: This smells UB.

Comment: @Ian SIZEOFRAW=10 Its 2d array but Iimple.ented in my whole program as a 1d. I play with pointers a lot.

Comment: @Eugene Do you mean why I used calloc ?

Comment: I mean that your code is never using index `0` anywhere, which is making me suspect you afraid of accessing the array element number `0`.

Comment: @Eugene I have to calculate the numbers I could use i-1 but I don't want to add -1 everywhere :p

Comment: If you're sure the database doesn't change (or shouldn't change) then you should mark it as const so that the compiler enforces it.

Comment: @wybourn The value of database can change later in my program because I use realloc() but this is a diffrent functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, `numberSeen` contents in not initializes.

I suppose that the intention was

```
        for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
            numbersSeen[i]=0;
```

instead of redundant initialization of `numberCount`.